# Melhor forma de exibir um form dentro de outro form?

Tags: c#

Estou em dúvida aqui, não conheço muito sobre isso.

**1** Estava usando um `form` apenas, com vários `panel` ocultos dentro dele, e quando o usuário clicava em alguma opção no `menuStrip` eu manipulava as propriedades `Enabled` e `Visible` dos correspondentes painéis. Porém estava dando bug, o banco de dados não estava gravando o conteúdo digitado.

**2** Tentei usando `splitContainer`, mas continua com bug, não de salvar, mas demora muito aparecer o formulário e para salvar. Tentei com o código:

```
splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Clear(); // limpa o painel2
nvCli.TopLevel = false; // não alinha ao topo
nvCli.AutoScroll = true; // exibe barra de rolagem automaticamente
splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(nvCli); //add formulario ao painel 2
nvCli.Show(); // mostra formulario
```

Onde `nvCli` é uma instância estática e publica de outro formulário.
Outro problema aqui é que o formulário não estava sendo exibido no centro da do `panel2`, estava ficando torto.

Queria saber se há outra forma melhor pra exibir ou como solucionar os bugs?

**Layout da interface (sim, fiz no paint kk)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Leonardo. Tudo bem?

Acho pouco vantajoso utilizar vários forms dentro de outro, além de tornar a interface muito complexa, tende a deixar o código bastante extenso.

Você tem um motivo realmente muito bom para fazer isso? Se não, lhe aconselho a utilizar forms com ShowModal mesmo, desde que não fiquem muitos sobrepostos, ou mesmo manter vários paineis ocultos e exibi-los quando necessário.

O erro de não estar salvando no banco precisa ser avaliado, pois provavelmente não está relacionado com os panels.

Comment: Não tenho motivo, é simplesmente porque eu não conheço nada pra fazer isso, o meu objetivo é mostrar um formulário (tabela do banco de dados, ou campos do banco de dados) diferente ao clicar em uma opção do menu strip, exemplo, quando clicar em cadastrar exibe o formulário de cadastro ali no "form aqui" (adicionei uma imagem do meu layout no post), daí quando ele clicar em outra opção ele desaparece com a que esta ativa e exibe o form da outra

Comment: Leonardo, para este tipo de cenário, analise se utilizar a estratégia MDI não seria adequado. Há muito material sobre Aplicações MDI na internet.

Answer (score 1):

Tinha uma solução meio no estilo gambiarra, erá só você deixar os elementos que devem aparecer quando o form for iniciado visíveis e o restante (esse form oculto) deve estar invisível (visible=false), e quando o usuário clicar neste menustrip estes elementos ficariam visíveis.

É uma solução bem "manual" e "deselegante", mas pra quê ter um código elegante né mesmo? Só tenha certeza de que tudo vai funcionar e você depois vai entender tudo, caso precise fazer uma manutenção no código.

Comment: Para isso eu estava usando o painel, pra 'agrupar' esses elementos... Estou usando agora o slipContainer, pois foi a opção que achei mais ideal (resolvi os bugs que aconteciam)